# Firebase database DataSnapshot not working

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to show the logged in user a welcome message based on their gender. If 'male', then `setText("Hello Sir, your mail is: " + user.getEmail())` and for else,  `setText("Hello Madam, your mail is: " + user.getEmail())`. This is my databse structure:
[image]

This is the profile activity java that I'm working on:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import com.firebase.client.DataSnapshot;
import com.firebase.client.Firebase;
import com.firebase.client.FirebaseError;
import com.firebase.client.ValueEventListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class ProfileActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView textViewUserEmail;

    private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    public DatabaseReference myRef;
    public String userID;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle saveInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(saveInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        mFirebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = mFirebaseDatabase.getReference();
        final FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
        userID = user.getUid();
        DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("UsersMale");

        textViewUserEmail = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textViewUserEmail);
        loadUserInformation();

        ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String myStrign = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
                if (user.isEmailVerified() && myStrign.equals("male")) {
                    textViewUserEmail.setText("Hello Sir, your mail is: " + user.getEmail());
                } else {
                    textViewUserEmail.setText("Hello Madam, your mail is: " + user.getEmail());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
        });
    }

}
}
```

The code is returning an error. Can you please suggest me what I'm doing wrong here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is happening because the query returns an object while you are parsing it as a string. `String myStrign = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);`. You need to define a POJO  that can convert your returned snapshot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please give an example of the answer? @M.WaqasPervez

Comment: Also there is not any node in your firebase structure with key `Users`.

Comment: Did you just assume the gender of the user?

Comment: Oh! Yes, that was a mistake. @M.WaqasPervez

Comment: I've updated the image, I guess, it will now be less confusing. @PeterHaddad. Let's assume all the `Gender: "male"`. Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the database structure to this:

```
 users
   uniqueId
        name: superman
        gender: male
   uniqueId
        name: girl
        gender: female
```

No need to have two parent nodes `UserMale` and `UserFemale`, just create one node call it `users` and each user will have an attribute gender.

then do this:

```
FirebaseUser user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
String userID = user.getUid();
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users");

ref.child(userID).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String gender=dataSnapshot.child("gender").getValue().toString();
            if(gender.equals("male")) {
                textViewUserEmail.setText("Hello Sir, your mail is: " + user.getEmail());
            } else {
                textViewUserEmail.setText("Hello Madam, your mail is: " + user.getEmail());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {}
    });
}
```

First retrieve the userid then put the location at `users`, then attach a listener and retrieve the gender value of the logged in user.

Comment: Okay, I had the problem with importing `com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener` but after currecting that, now it says, `Class 'Anonymous class derived from ValueEventListener' must either be declared abstract or implement abstract method on 'onDataChange(DataSnapshot)' in 'ValueEventListener'`. What could be the problem here?

Comment: @Ashonko https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ValueEventListener ValueEventListener is an interface, when you implement an interface than you must override all of it's methods. Just let android studio auto complete it... When you write new ValueEventListener it should automatically write the methods of that interface..